# Mapping values in JOLT and loop for corresponding IDs

Tags: arrays, json, mapping, transform, jolt

I need to transform below Input JSON where the ID has multiple ORG_LVL_2 codes and it should fall under the same OrgUnits array, whereas in my spec a separate object is getting created.

```json
[
  {
    "id": "0000606800",
    "ORG_LVL_2": "Co0053"
  },
  {
    "id": "0000606800",
    "ORG_LVL_2": "Co0054"
  },
  {
    "id": "0000609480",
    "ORG_LVL_2": "Co0055"
  }
]
```

as Output JSON:

```json
{
  "IntegrationEntities": {
    "integrationEntity": [
      {
        "integrationEntityHeader": {
          "referenceCodeForEntity": "test"
        },
        "integrationEntityDetails": {
          "glAccount": {
            "id": "0000606800",
            "orgUnits": {
              "orgUnitAssignment": [
                {
                  "orgUnitDetails": [
                    {
                      "orgUnitLevel": "ORG_LVL_1",
                      "orgUnitCode": "C01"
                    },
                    {
                      "orgUnitLevel": "ORG_LVL_2",
                      "orgUnitCode": "Co0053"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "orgUnitDetails": [
                    {
                      "orgUnitLevel": "ORG_LVL_1",
                      "orgUnitCode": "C01"
                    },
                    {
                      "orgUnitLevel": "ORG_LVL_2",
                      "orgUnitCode": "Co0054"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "integrationEntityHeader": {
          "referenceCodeForEntity": "test"
        },
        "integrationEntityDetails": {
          "glAccount": {
            "id": "0000609480",
            "orgUnits": {
              "orgUnitAssignment": [
                {
                  "orgUnitDetails": [
                    {
                      "orgUnitLevel": "ORG_LVL_1",
                      "orgUnitCode": "C01"
                    },
                    {
                      "orgUnitLevel": "ORG_LVL_2",
                      "orgUnitCode": "Co0055"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is my spec but the output is not as expected:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "#test": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.[&1].integrationEntityHeader.referenceCodeForEntity",
        "id": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.[&1].integrationEntityDetails.glAccount.id",
        "#ORG_LVL_1": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.[&1].integrationEntityDetails.glAccount.orgUnits.orgUnitAssignment.orgUnitDetails.[0].orgUnitLevel",
        "#CO1": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.[&1].integrationEntityDetails.glAccount.orgUnits.orgUnitAssignment.orgUnitDetails.[0].orgUnitCode",
        "#ORG_LVL_2": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.[&1].integrationEntityDetails.glAccount.orgUnits.orgUnitAssignment.orgUnitDetails.[1].orgUnitLevel",
        "ORG_LVL_2": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.[&1].integrationEntityDetails.glAccount.orgUnits.orgUnitAssignment.orgUnitDetails.[1].orgUnitCode"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "IntegrationEntities": {
        "integrationEntity": {
          "*": {
            "integrationEntityHeader": {
              "referenceCodeForEntity": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.[&2].integrationEntityHeader.referenceCodeForEntity"
            },
            "integrationEntityDetails": {
              "glAccount": {
                "id": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.[&3].integrationEntityDetails.glAccount.id",
                "orgUnits": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.[&3].integrationEntityDetails.glAccount.orgUnits"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I will appreciate any help that comes my way. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might construct the spec based on partitioning by id values in the beginning such as

```json
[
  { // partition by "id" values while hardcoding for the attributes "ORG_LVL_1" and "C01"
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "id": "@1,id.&",
        "O*": {
          "#ORG_LVL_1|$": "@2,id.&2.orgUnitLevel",
          "#C01|@": "@2,id.&2.orgUnitCode"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // dissipate each component of the independent arrays to their respective indexes 
    // in order to generate the desired objects
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "#test": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity[#2].integrationEntityHeader.referenceCodeForEntity",
        "$": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity[#2].integrationEntityDetails.glAccount.id",
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity[#4].integrationEntityDetails.glAccount.orgUnits.orgUnitAssignment[&2].orgUnitDetails[&].&1"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of redundantly generated null values
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=recursivelySquashNulls"
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much that helped..

There's minor modification in the input instead of ORG_LVL_2 its "LVL2" but we need the same output in orgUnits:
Input:

```
[
    {
        "id": "0000606800",
        "status": "Active",
        "name": "Office Supplies",
        "LVL2": "208"
    }
]
```

also in the output along with the id, I want to display status, "name" as "glAccountDescription" and same as "glAccountName" along with id which will also become "glAccountCode", required output as below:

```
                    "glAccount": {
                        "id": "00000001",
                        "status": "ACTIVE",
                        "glAccountName": "01 A/P Voucher Logging",
                        "glAccountDescription": "A/P Voucher Logging",
                        "glAccountCode": "0001",
                        "glAccountTypeId": "GLTYPE001",
                        "orgUnits":
```

Comment: it looks like you might be trying to ask another question. Please open a new question, or no one will see it as this has already been answered.